# AJAX - Print Page Content

Tags: php, ajax

I am using AJAX to send form data to a server php file that builds and sends an html email. A portion of this data I am echoing on the server php file. The html that is echoed builds a table that I would like the user to print (on paper). I'd like to open the default browser print dialog so the user can print the table that he/she cannot see. I don't care if a new tab has to open displaying the echoed content. Is this even possible?

Comment: you can use javascript, to prompt to print a page the user is on. The rest of the question is just a little fuzzy.

Comment: Please clarify: Is the requirement to print INVISIBLE content? If not you can spawn the print dialog via javascript: window.print()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

return that html form ajax request and then use javascript to print

***This code is not tested***

**JQuery/Javascript**

```
$.post("EmailFile.php", { "EmailParam": "EmailVal" },
     function(data){
         var HTML = data.EmailHTML;

        var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow", "width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
        WindowObject.document.writeln(HTML);
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();

     }, "json");
```

**PHP File** (EmailFile.php)

```
$EmailData = $_POST['EmailParam'];
//...Send Email...

//..Build HTML...
$TableHTML = "<table></table>";

//Return HTML
$JSONArr['EmailHTML'] = $TableHTML;
echo json_encode($JSONArr);
```

Comment: This is close, thanks. Currently I'm trying to work out an issue with the above code where WindowObject is null and the popup that is opened just says undefined, but this is a good start. I just gotta get the returned html to be written in the new window.

Comment: Got it! The JSON stuff is unnecessary. I just `echo $TableHTML`, save `var HTML = data;` and `WindowObject.document.write(HTML);`. I've updated your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to print invisible content you could use two different css files for the different media (screen vs print) where you hide/unhide the required content via *display: none;* and then spawn the print dialog via *window.print()*.

Your question is a little confusing.

For instance:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme1.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme2.css" media="print" />
<div class="hidden_on_page">YOU CAN'T SEE ME BUT YOU CAN PRINT ME!</div>
<div class="on_page">YOU CAN SEE ME BUT YOU CAN'T PRINT ME</div>
```

Then in theme1.css:

```
.hidden_on_page { display: none; }
```

Then in theme2.css:

```
.on_page { display: none; }
```

And you would trigger the print dialog to spawn when required via:

```
window.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find solution there is complete code:

http://codexhelp.blogspot.in/2017/04/php-ajax-window-print-page-content.html

```
<script>
function printContent(id){ 

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'printContent.php',
            data: {id: id},
            type: 'get',
            success: function( response ) {



            var contents = response;


            var idname = name;


            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');

            frameDoc.document.write('<style>table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; width:100%; margin-top:20px;} .table td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > thead > tr > th{ padding:8px 18px;  } .table-bordered, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th, .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .table-bordered > thead > tr > th {     border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;} </style>');

            // your title
            frameDoc.document.title = "Print Content with ajax in php";


            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
            return false;   




            }
        });

}
</script>
```

Comment: I have suggested an edit that involves altering your layout to a style that more clearly displays the structure of your code, which aids in bebugging / analysing your code.  Spreading your `<style>` line across several lines would be especially helpful in understanding it.