# Javascript overwrites data on screen and refreshes page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been working on a project that I just need to print the contents of a hidden `div`. The below solution works fine, but replaces the page contents with the `div` then calls the print of the window and then replaces the page with the original contents. This is fine, but when I click on the page after this or try to print again, the page refreshes.

Is there a way, without opening a new window to print the contents of a `div` and the page still be functional?

```
$scope.printDiv = function(printable) {
    var restorePage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printContent = document.getElementById(printable).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +  printContent  + "</body>";
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorePage;
    };
```

Comment: Put the id in double quotes; document.getElementById("printable").innerHTML;
And how about this at line 4: document.body.innerHTML = printContent;

Answer (score 0):

I had created a directive that did something much like this. It involves creating a new window, populating it with the HTML you want printed, printing that window, and then finally closing.

The code looks like the following:

```
$scope.printPage = function() {
    var pageToPrint = $window.open('', 'Print Page', 'width=800, height=600');
    pageToPrint.document.write(angular.element(pageHtml).html());
    pageToPrint.document.close();
    pageToPrint.focus();
    pageToPrint.print();
    pageToPrint.close();
}
```

This works in all of the browsers and cleanly closes everything out once the user finishes with the print dialog window.

Comment: I had done this same thing prior this morning and it was working with static data. Each hidden `div` has different information in it and it wasn't pulling in the different data.

Comment: @BrandonWilson then it sounds like your question isn't 'how to print html' but 'how to get the correct html'. That's quite different than what you posted. You would need a whole new question with additional code for that.

Answer (score 0):

See a similar question that I found: [AJAX - Print Page Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215151/ajax-print-page-content)

It seems the [answer of Matt Razza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11215242/1078110) is what You are looking for.

> If you're trying to print invisible content you could use two
>   different css files for the different media (screen vs print) where
>   you hide/unhide the  required content via display: none; and then
>   spawn the print dialog via window.print().
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme1.css" media="screen" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme2.css" media="print" />
> <div class="hidden_on_page">YOU CAN'T SEE ME BUT YOU CAN PRINT ME!</div>
> <div class="on_page">YOU CAN SEE ME BUT YOU CAN'T PRINT ME</div>
> ```
>
> Then in theme1.css:
>
> ```
> .hidden_on_page { display: none; }
> ```
>
> theme 2.css:
>
> ```
> .on_page { display: none; }
> ```
>
> And you would trigger the print dialog to spawn when required via:
>
> ```
> window.print();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/356123/1516112

When the user click on your button, wrap your entire page inside a `div` using the `.no-print` class. Next add your content in another div next to the previous `div`. Call `print()` and restore your page. It should works.